# Bad replace url with query params react router 5.2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, react-router, react-hooks

i have a search component that is transversal, the search component redirect to /items?search=:search, :search is the content of an input of component. The first time that i use the search component it works but when i try to use this component in /items?search:search it redirect to /items?search=null.

The component in question is:

```js
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

// Hook function from https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters
// A custom hook that builds on useLocation to parse
// the query string for you.
function useQuery() {
  return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
}

/**
 * 
 * @returns 
 */
export function HeaderComponent() {
  let history = useHistory();
  let query = useQuery();
  let value = query.get('search') != null 
    ? query.get('search') 
    : '';

  // Search callback.
  const search = useCallback(
    function() {
      let searchName = document.getElementById('query-search').value;
      history.replace({
        pathname: '/items',
        search: `?search=${searchName}`
      });
    },
    [history]
  );

  return (
    <header>
      <div className="container">
        <img src="">
        </img>
        <form className="">
          <fieldset>
            <input id="query-search" 
              type="text" 
              defaultValue={ value } />
            <button onClick={ search }></button>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The dependicies of the proyect are:

```
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
"node-sass": "^6.0.1",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
"web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
```

Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

I change the handle of query param using form submit:

```js
const [search, updateSearch] = useState('');

// Set search value.
const setSearch = (e) => {
  updateSearch(e.target.value);
}

// Handle form submit, redirect to search item.
const formSubmit = () => {
  history.push({
    pathname: '/items',
    search: `?search=${encodeURI(search)}`
  });
}

// Functional component return
return (
  <header>
    <div className="container">
      <Link to="/">
        <img src={ logo } >
        </img>
      </Link>
      <form onSubmit={ formSubmit }>
        <fieldset>
          <input id="query-search" 
            type="text" 
            defaultValue={ value }
            onChange={ setSearch }
            name="search" />
          <button></button>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </header>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dependecy value of React.useCallback it is the query value, because this memoized your function to the previos value

```js
const search = useCallback(
    function() {
      let searchName = document.getElementById('query-search').value;
      history.replace({
        pathname: '/items',
        search: `?search=${searchName}`
      });
    },
    [history, value]
  );
```

try that.